# Xpath not contains

Tags: xpath, contains

Is there a way to select the xpath which doesn't contain `ng-show` 
Please find the xpath below: 
I'm familiar with not(contains()), but it has 2 parameters.
I would like it to not contain the `ng-show`itself, because I have a few more element containing ng-show and I don't want to select any of them.

```
<span ng-show="displayValue" class="ng-binding">0 km</span>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below `xpath`

```
//span[not(@ng-show)][not(@class='percent ng-binding')][@class='ng-binding']
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Only those `<span>` tag will return, which attribute does not contains `ng-show`

Comment: Hi Janish, Yes I tried, it doesn't work.
I had to add it to the xpath I had before , so I get this statement overall, and it doesn't work


`//*[contains(@class,"ng-binding") and not(contains(@class,"percent ng-binding")) and span[not(@ng-show)]]`

Comment: But I have other conditions as well that must be written under the same statement :)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: It is working for me, with out showing any error. make sure before reach to this element provide some wait. so your driver may able to find the webelement.